# Regular expression Dutch postal code in Angular with html 5 pattern

Tags: javascript, regex, angular, validation

I have a Angular 8 application and I am working on a profile form with `ngForm` so that users can fill in data about them self, like a postal cod.e I am using a regular expression for postal code, like this: ddddll(1234AA) for example.

Googled, tutorials

So I have this for checking the regular expression for Postal code:

```
<div class="input-group col-4">
  <label for="zipCode">{{ getLabel('zipCode') }}</label>
  <input type="text" id="zipCode" name="zipCode" [(ngModel)]="profile.zipCode" #zipCode="ngModel" pattern="[1-9][0-9]{3}\s?[a-zA-Z]{2}" maxlength=7>
  <span class="help-block alert alert-danger errorColorMessage" [hidden]="zipCode.valid || zipCode.pristine">Postcode kan enkel vier nummers en twee letters bevatten  </span>
</div>
```

But the error message:

```
<span class="help-block alert alert-danger errorColorMessage" [hidden]="zipCode.valid || zipCode.pristine">Postcode kan enkel vier nummers en twee letters bevatten  </span>
```

Will be already showing when I start typing for example with the number 1.

That the regular expression for postal code will be working correctly.

Oke, I made a variable, like this:

```
POSTALCODE_REGEXP  = '[1-9][0-9]{3}\s?[a-zA-Z]{2}';
```

But how do  I check it now with this:

```
   <div class="input-group col-4">
                  <label for="zipCode">{{ getLabel('zipCode') }}</label>
                  <input type="text" id="zipCode" name="zipCode" [(ngModel)]="profile.zipCode" #zipCode = "ngModel"
                  pattern="[1-9][0-9]{3}\s?[a-zA-Z]{2}" maxlength=7>
                  <span class="help-block alert alert-danger errorColorMessage" [hidden]="zipCode.valid || zipCode.pristine">Postcode kan enkel vier nummers en twee letters bevatten  </span>
                </div>
```

Oke,

I made a seperated function like this:

```
  import { AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';

export function postalCodeValidator(
  control: AbstractControl
): { [key: string]: any } | null {
  const valid = /(\d{4}[A-Z][A-Z])/.test(control.value);
  return valid
    ? null
    : { invalidNumber: { valid: false, value: control.value } }
}
```

and my html template looks like this:

```
  <div class="input-group col-4">
                  <label for="zipCode">{{ getLabel('zipCode') }}</label>
                  <input type="text" id="zipCode" name="zipCode" #zipCode = "ngModel" [(ngModel)]="profile.zipCode" postalCodeValidator  maxlength=7>

                  <span *ngIf="zipCode.errors">
                    Zip code is invalid
                  </span>


                </div>
```

Oke,

I have it now like this:

```
  <div class="input-group col-4">
                  <label for="zipCode">{{ getLabel('zipCode') }}</label>
                  <input type="text" id="zipCode" name="zipCode" #zipCode = "ngModel" [(ngModel)]="profile.zipCode" [pattern]="zipCodePattern"   maxlength=50>
                </div>
```

an the ts file like this:

```
zipCodePattern = '\d{4}[A-Z][A-Z]';
```

I also tried this:

```
  <div class="input-group col-4">
                  <label for="zipCode">{{ getLabel('zipCode') }}</label>
                  <input type="text" id="zipCode" name="zipCode" #zipCode = "ngModel" [(ngModel)]="profile.zipCode" [pattern]="zipCodePattern"   maxlength=50>
                  <span class="help-block alert alert-danger errorColorMessage"  *ngIf="zipCode.errors?.pattern">
                    Postcode niet geldig.
                  </span>
                </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried the reactive forms instead of template driven forms? There is a min length validator.

Comment: Absolutely none of this has anything to do with the jQuery Validate plugin.  Please do not "tag-spam".   Edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oke, I solved already. Like this:

```
zipCodePattern =  /^\d{4} ?[a-z]{2}$/i;
```

Comment: Glad you solved it. I wasn't able to get back to you due to being at work, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the pattern should change while you are typing. You can't straight up tell the pattern that you're expecting between 1 - 4 letters first before expecting 1 - 2 numbers, simply because the pattern will not match whilst typing. It depends on the current value's length. If You've typed in less than or equal to 4 characters, the pattern should be `/^[0-9]{profile.zipCode.length}/i`. From there on out, the pattern needs to match: `/^[0-9]{4}[a-z]{profile.zipCode.length - 4,2}/i`.

So I'd suggest storing the pattern in a variable, and changing it based on the length of the zipcode.

Comment: Do you have some sources for your claims? It works fine when I use it here: https://jsfiddle.net/rhybLc4s/ The validation is only done after hitting the submit button.

Comment: If a validator matches against your pattern, it will return false. https://regex101.com/r/82g2i2/1

Comment: Yes, but my point is that in my example the validation is done when the submit button is hit. Not on key press. It would really surprise me if you would have to modify a regex dynamically.

Comment: Right. He's using ngForms and its trying to validate his form. It will not match and flag the field as invalid.

Comment: So has somebody any suggestion? Thank you

Comment: I did. Reread the answer carefully. Put the pattern in brackets like so: ```[pattern]="zipCodePattern"``` and follow the rest of the suggestion.

Comment: If a user enters "1999 RT", selects the 999 and starts typing to change that into 000. That won't work then?